# Get media_type to fetch correct insights in a single request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

The metadata can be fetched using the following endpoint, `{post-id}?metadata=1` and it can have type either `shadowigcomment` or `shadowigmedia`. If the type if the later, is there a way to know the `media_type` so the correct insights could be fetched in a single request to minimize the api calls?

To clarify more, the image post and vide post insights are engagement, impressions, reach, saved. In case of video, there is another metric which is `video_views`. If I send the `video_views` metric in the request and it turned out to be an image post, I would get an error. If I don't and I get a vide post, I would have to send another request to just fetch the video views. Any chance this issue could be done in a single request.

I have also tried to get the media_type along with the metadata as follow: `{post_id}?metadata=1&fields=media_type` but there is also an issue. If the happens to be a comment, an error is thrown stating `"Tried accessing nonexisting field (media_type) on node type (ShadowIGComment)"`.

What I am asking for is a way to get the metadata of an object in one request and then fetch all fields and insights in just another single so as not to cause an overhead on the api call count.

Comment: Where do you get your post ids from to begin with?

Comment: I just send a request to {my-instagram-business-account-id}/media and I get a list of all of the posts.